# cant set Authorization Header in HttpClient ( .Net core 3.1 )

Tags: httpclient, .net-core-3.1

I am migrating from .net core 2.2 to 3.1. I am making an XUnit test method to test my controllers.
I successfully made and tested in .net core 2.2 projects, but after migrating to 3.1 it seems it cant set authorization header to my request so I am getting UnAuthorized from my app.

this is my Code :

```
    [Fact]
    public async void InvalidId_UnSuccessFull_GetById()
    {
        // Arrange
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var token = await GetAdminAccessToken(); // Sends a login request and fetch a valid token
       // httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization",$"Bearer {token}");
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization=new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Authorization",$"Bearer {token}");
        var id = Guid.Empty;

        // Act
        var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("localhost:5000/Admin/User/{id}");
        var message = await ExtractMessage(response);


        // Assert
        Assert.Contains(PersianErrorMessage.InvalidUserId, message);
        Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, response.StatusCode);
    }
```

I debugged into httpClient class till the sendAsync method and the HttpRequestMessage request instance does not have an Authorization Header that I set above! What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

The AuthenticationHeaderValue should be set like this:

```cs
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
```

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.headers.authenticationheadervalue.-ctor?view=netcore-3.1#System_Net_Http_Headers_AuthenticationHeaderValue__ctor_System_String_

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues that could trip you up here.  This can be a frustrating issue, so hopefully, this helps.  The HTTP client is more than likely sending the Authorization header.  If there is any kind of redirect, the Authorization header does not travel with it.  I ran into this issue once and the only problem was my original URL did not have a **trailing slash at the end**.

What I entered:
https://api.example.com/v3/endpoint

Server endpoint:
https://api.example.com/v3/endpoint/

- Step 1, Determine if there is a redirect.
- Step 2, Make your URL match the final URI **exactly**

Clients like curl do this automatically.  In .Net 3.1, you will have to make sure your client checks for redirects.  A 401 error is actually a good thing--it means you more than likely reached the right endpoint albeit without the authorization token.

You can do this in code, but just run debug and break after you get the response.  Examine the **RequestURI** property of the **RequestMessage** object of the **HttpResponseMessage** (response.RequestMessage.RequestURI).  Compare this with your initial URL.  If they do not match exactly, you've been redirected and the Authorization header was lost along the way.